# gae loads all javascripts everytime the page is refesh

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

When I refresh the page, all javascripts file are load again. I think it is the reason why it is too slow to access the page.
[image]

Is there any way to fix this problem? I mean just loads javascripts for the first time the page is accessed. When the page is reload, it is not necessary to reloads all javascript files again.

Comment: you can have the client get them from a cdn, minimized. getting from multiple domains will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- the default cache expiration config in the app.yaml, if you serve those resources statically: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Static_cache_expiration
- the per-handler cache control: see this Q&A [unable to set cache expiration on in app.yaml for a python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289752/unable-to-set-cache-expiration-on-in-app-yaml-for-a-python-app)

Not sure if you are familiar with these recommendations, they *might* help as well: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching

> Blockquote